# Replacement for SimpleConsumer.send in kafka?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

SimpleConsumer has been deprecated in kafka, with org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer being the replacement. However, it doesn't have a send(...) function. How can I rewrite the below code using the new KafkaConsumer?

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import kafka.api.TopicMetadataRequest
import kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer
....
val consumer = new SimpleConsumer(
    host = "127.0.0.1",
    port = 9092,
    soTimeout = 2.seconds.toMillis.toInt,
    bufferSize = 1024,
    clientId = "health-check")

// this will fail if Kafka is unavailable
consumer.send(new TopicMetadataRequest(Nil, 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get topic metadata with [`.partitionsFor`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.java#L1462) and [`.listTopics`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.java#L1492)

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct replacement for method ,it depends what you want to do .
If you need all partitions info there is method for that consumer.partitionFor(topic) in the new api